# Convert from html string to pdf using itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf, itext

I'm using `iTextSharp` in my project and using this method to parse html string to pdf

```
public static MemoryStream MakePdf(string htmlCode)
        {
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(htmlCode);

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            document.Open();
            worker.StartDocument();
            worker.Parse(reader); // EXCEPTION IN THIS LINE!!!!
            worker.EndDocument();
            worker.Close();
            document.Close();

            return msOutput;
        }
```

And it doesn't work for me. It throws an exception at selected line

> URI formats are not supported.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S. Here is html I need to parse

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="Boomer" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {
           font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
           width: 100%;
           font-family: Myriad Pro;
           font-style: italic;
           background: #f3f3f3;
        }

        @font-face 
        {
            font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
            src: url('../fonts/myriadpro.eot');
            src: url('../fonts/myriadpro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('../fonts/myriadpro.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('../fonts/myriadpro.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        .clear
        {
            clear: both;
        }

        a,.blue_text
        {
            color:#2aa2f6;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .simple_title
        {
           font-size: 22px; 
        }

        .text750
        {
            width: 750px;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        .full_width_text
        {
            margin-right: 35px;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        .grey_text 
        {
            color:#afafaf;
        }

        .email_page
        {
            width: 1025px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

        .email_page p
        {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .email_div
        {
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #fff;
            width: 998px;
            border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
            border-radius: 10px;
           -webkit-border-radius:10px;
           -border-radius:10px;
           -moz-border-radius:10px;
           -o-border-radius:10px;
            display: table;
        }

        .email_content 
        {
            margin-left: 60px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        .email_logo
        {
            float: left;
        }

        .email_title
        {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 130px;
            font-size: 22px;
            color:#f7941d;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .email_img_container
        {
            float: right;
            width: 270px;
        }

        .email_img_container .text_description
        {
            font-size: 18px;
            color:#000000;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .email_img_container img
        {
            border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
            border-radius: 10px;
           -webkit-border-radius:10px;
           -border-radius:10px;
           -moz-border-radius:10px;
           -o-border-radius:10px;
        }

        .text600
        {
            width: 600px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Voucher</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="email_page">

    <div class="email_div">
        <div class="email_content">
           <div class="text600">
                <div class="email_logo">
                    <a href="#"> 
                        <img src="{EmailLogo}"  />
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="email_title">
                    Instant Gift Certificate
                </div>  
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div>
                    <p>To: <span class="blue_text">{RecipientName}</span></p>
                    <p>
                    <div>{GiftVoucherName}</div>
                    <div>{GiftVoucherDescription}</div>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        This gift is from:  <span class="blue_text">{SenderName}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="email_img_container">
                <div class="text_description">
                    <div>SG Code: {SGCode}</div>
                    <div>Purchased on: {PurchaseDate}</div>
                </div>
                <img src="{MerchantImage}" alt="" />
            </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         <div class="text750">
            <p>
                This gift must be redeemed by: <span class="blue_text">{Date}</span><br />
                Redeemable at the following locations: <span class="blue_text">{Locations}</span><br />
                For other details and terms and conditions, please see the other attachment. 



            </p>

            <div class="simple_title">
                Disclaimer
            </div>
            <p>
                Test.com is not responsible for the content of the message or the selection of the gift by the sender.
                Once the sender enters the information, the instant gift is automatically generated and sent to
                the recipient.
            </p>
            <p>
                Visit us at: <a href="http://www.Test.com">www.Test.com</a>
            </p>
         </div>


        </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated in favor of XML Worker. That's the Java terminology for saying you're using functionality that is no longer supported because it has been replaced by new functionality. I don't know the corresponding C# terminology.

Comment: I've tried with new XmlWorker, XmlWorkerHelper, but it doesn't work again.

Comment: Well, maybe you've hit something that isn't supported (URI formats?) but it's hard to tell what isn't working based on the sole information that "it isn't working." We need more info to know what's going wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question and added my html too... Hopefully, you can find wrong part there...

Comment: HTMLWorker (as opposed to XML Worker) will ignore all the CSS, so... that certainly won't work. Also, I assume that the parts between curly brackets like {EmailLogo} are replaced by something. If not, you'll certainly get an URI error caused by this tag: <img src="{EmailLogo}"  />

Comment: I've replaced my code to XmlWorker and now it doesn't throw exception. But it makes empty pdf file... The parts between curly brackets had replaced for sure before sending.

Comment: That's strange. I can't help you with that until I start writing my next book. Currently I don't have the time for that (I'm rewriting the book about digital signatures). Also SO asks me to "please avoid extended discussions in comments." I guess you'll have to ask somebody else for help.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you can add Providers to your HTMLWorker using the `SetProviders` method which takes an IDictionary the HTMLWorker class has constants for the string keys. In your case have a look at the ILinkProvider and/or IImageProvider. These provide a way to handle the images and URLs inside of your HTML yourself, translating them into usable parts for the PDF.